# react router dom Link component error in react typescript

Tags: typescript, react-router

```
<Link style={{textDecoration: 'none'}} to={{
            state: { fromDashboard: true },      
            pathname:`/Forum/thread/${thread.threadLink}`,
          }} >
            {thread.title}
</Link>
```

This code gives me the following error on the second line, which I don't understand since I'm following the react router dom docs...

Type '{ state: { fromDashboard: true; }; pathname: string; }' is not assignable to type 'To'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'state' does not exist in type 'Partial'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(70, 5): The expected type comes from property 'to' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LinkProps & RefAttributes'

using:
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.8.0",

tried state:'string' as well and moving it below the pathname and it's still an issue

and i tried doing the following:
npm uninstall --save-dev @types/react-router
npm uninstall --save-dev @types/react-router-dom
npm un -D @types/react-router
npm un -D @types/react-router-dom
npm i -S react@18 react-dom@18

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

According to the declaration of To type
/**

- Describes a location that is the destination of some navigation, either via
- `history.push` or `history.replace`. May be either a URL or the pieces of a
- URL path.
  */

[image]

So you should try

```
<Link style={{textDecoration: 'none'}} to={`/Forum/thread/${thread.threadLink}`} >
```